# Getting a slice of trait objects from a slice of an associated type

Tags: rust, type-conversion, trait-objects

I have two related traits `List` and `ListItem` ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5930c34901694601a542ce64b4840047)).

```rust
trait List {
    type Item: ListItem;
    fn items(&self) -> Vec<Self::Item>;
    /* more stuff */
}
```

where `Item` is an associated type on `List` and `ListItem` has a custom implementation for `PartialEq` and `Debug`

Inside of a `List` trait method that looks like

```
fn foo(&self, other: &dyn List<Item=Self::Item>)
```

I would like to compare sub-slices of the items, using the `PartialEq` defined for `ListItem`.
e.g.

```
let lhs: &[&dyn ListItem] = ...;
let rhs: &[&dyn ListItem] = ...;
assert_eq!(lhs, rhs);
```

but I cannot coerce the slices to the correct type.

```rust
fn foo(&self, other: &dyn List<Item = Self::Item>) {
   let items = self.items();
   let items_slice: &[&dyn ListItem] = items.as_slice(); // <-- Error here
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   |
40 |         let these: &[&dyn ListItem] = these_items.as_slice();
   |                    ----------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&[&dyn ListItem]`, found `&[<Self as List>::Item]`
   |                    |
   |                    expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[&dyn ListItem]`
              found reference `&[<Self as List>::Item]`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<Self as List>::Item` to `&dyn ListItem`
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5930c34901694601a542ce64b4840047))

How can I coerce the slice to the correct type?

Comment: trust me just don't use dyn unless you really really know why you are using dyn and there is no other solution, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bcfdf2774761968f3c6bf5511fe01b60

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the linked playground does not do what I am trying to do. Specifically "I would like to compare sub-slices of the items, using the `PartialEq` defined for `ListItem`". Including `where Self::Item: PartialEq` will not use the PartialEq implementation for `ListItem`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfd704ff4d4f51fad519fb001c44de88

Comment: Relying on the users of the trait to correctly define a `PartialEq` that works in the way expected by the trait would prevent structs from defining their own `PartialEq` implementation. It would be cleaner to define a separate `struct ListItem` and change the interface to accept `Into<ListItem>`.

Comment: Adding an `eq` method to the trait makes things ugly. `!lhs.eq(rhs)` looks much worse than `lhs != rhs`, and there is no clean way to assert that collections of the trait are equal, like in this question, where I am trying to assert if two slices containing references to items that implement the trait, are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. First, you need references, and `items` contains owned items. Second, you need fat references, and `items` has concrete types.

You need to collect them into a `Vec`:

```rust
let items = self.items();
let items_dyn = items
    .iter()
    .map(|item| item as &dyn ListItem)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```